# What are the correct audio levels for Voice and Music in a web promo video?

Tags: video, audio, mixing, engineering

I'm editing a promo video that will appear on the web (specifically, [PledgeMusic](http://www.pledgemusic.com/)) and I'm curious what is the current best practice for the correct audio levels (base -dB) for:

- Music (when no other sound is present)
- Music (when a voice is also speaking)
- Voice (when music is played at the same time)